# Fetch first 10 rows with IN Operation

Tags: sql, plsql, db2-luw

I want to fetch first 10 rows as per below condition and also where tabname = 'TABLE1' and 'TABLE2' (if these tables are not in first 10 rows even)

First 10 rows as per below condition is working fine:

```
db2 "select substr(a.tabname,1,30) as TABNAME,
> a.rows_read as RowsRead,
> (a.rows_read / (b.commit_sql_stmts + b.rollback_sql_stmts + 1)) as TBRRTX,
> (b.commit_sql_stmts + b.rollback_sql_stmts) as TXCNT
> from sysibmadm.snaptab a, sysibmadm.snapdb b
> where a.dbpartitionnum = b.dbpartitionnum
> and b.db_name = 'LIVE'
> order by a.rows_read desc fetch first 10 rows only"

TABNAME                        ROWSREAD             TBRRTX               TXCNT
------------------------------ -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
XOUTMSGLOG                              43845129056                   41           1049571334
SCHSTATUS                               35336410261                   33           1049571334
ADDRESS                                 26817245226                   25           1049571334
CATGRPDESC                              25628156703                   24           1049571334
ORDERITEMS                              23945555619                   22           1049571334
ORDERS                                  10656700035                   10           1049571334
XPAYINSTDATA                            10555959906                   10           1049571334
OFFER                                   10426958061                    9           1049571334
SCHBRDCST                               10286981444                    9           1049571334
ATTRVALDESC                              8327058697                    7           1049571334

  10 record(s) selected.
```

Now, requirement is to have 'TABLE1' and 'TABLE2' (if these tables are not in first 10 rows even) so how to add this condition in above statement?

So that it looks like below:

```
TABNAME                        ROWSREAD             TBRRTX               TXCNT
------------------------------ -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
XOUTMSGLOG                              43845129056                   41           1049571334
SCHSTATUS                               35336410261                   33           1049571334
ADDRESS                                 26817245226                   25           1049571334
CATGRPDESC                              25628156703                   24           1049571334
ORDERITEMS                              23945555619                   22           1049571334
ORDERS                                  10656700035                   10           1049571334
XPAYINSTDATA                            10555959906                   10           1049571334
OFFER                                   10426958061                    9           1049571334
SCHBRDCST                               10286981444                    9           1049571334
ATTRVALDESC                              8327058697                    7           1049571334
TABLE1                                        81444                    1           10495713341
TABLE2                                           97                    1           1049571334
 
 12 record(s) selected.
```

Comment: Add a second query for these additional two tables and use UNION ALL to put the two queries together

Answer (score 0):

A generic solution for whatever SELECT statement.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  -- Whatever SELECT statement with the desired expression 
  -- in the ORDER BY clause of the ROW_NUMBER function
  SELECT 
    TABNAME, COLCOUNT
  , ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY COLCOUNT DESC) AS RN_
  FROM SYSCAT.TABLES
  WHERE TABSCHEMA = 'SYSIBM'
)
WHERE RN_ <= 5 OR TABNAME IN ('SQLSCHEMAS', 'SQLTABLES')
ORDER BY RN_
```

| TABNAME | COLCOUNT | RN_ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SYSROUTINES | 84 | 1 |
| SYSTABLES | 83 | 2 |
| SYSINDEXES | 71 | 3 |
| SYSPLAN | 69 | 4 |
| ROUTINES | 56 | 5 |
| SQLSCHEMAS | 11 | 73 |
| SQLTABLES | 11 | 74 |

In your case:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT substr(a.tabname,1,30) as TABNAME,
  a.rows_read as RowsRead,

  --(a.rows_read / (b.commit_sql_stmts + b.rollback_sql_stmts + 1)) as TBRRTX,
  --(b.commit_sql_stmts + b.rollback_sql_stmts) as TXCNT
  A.ROWS_READ / NULLIF (B.TOTAL_APP_COMMITS + B.TOTAL_APP_ROLLBACKS, 0) as TBRRTX,
  B.TOTAL_APP_COMMITS + B.TOTAL_APP_ROLLBACKS as TXCNT,

  ROW_NUMBER () OVER (order by a.rows_read desc) AS RN_
  FROM 
  /*
  sysibmadm.snaptab a, sysibmadm.snapdb b
  where a.dbpartitionnum = b.dbpartitionnum
  --and b.db_name = 'LIVE'
  --order by a.rows_read desc fetch first 10 rows ONLY
  */
  -- It's better to use new MON functions instead of old SNAP ones
  TABLE (MON_GET_TABLE (NULL, NULL, -2)) a
  JOIN TABLE (MON_GET_DATABASE (-2)) b ON b.MEMBER = a.MEMBER
)
WHERE RN_ <= 10 OR TABNAME IN ('TABLE1', 'TABLE2')
ORDER BY RN_
```

BTW:
`sysibmadm.snapdb` returns info for a currently connected database only, since it's based on `SELECT ... FROM TABLE (SYSPROC.SNAP_GET_DB(' '))` (space as a parameter value means current database). So, the `b.db_name = 'LIVE'` predicate can only make your query return no rows, if you use wrong database name.